# Show Excel 2007 Ribbon in XLS file using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ribbon

I have an excel dashboard which works such that before the excel file is closed, I would like to display all the EXCEL ribbon, so that next time excel is opened, the application / excel will show the ribbon. At present, it does not show the ribbon if excel is opened.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(cancel As Boolean)

    On Error Resume Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
    Application.DisplayFullScreen = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.DisplayScrollBars = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sheets("Introduction").Select  
    
End Sub
```

This is an .xls file with Macro and supposed to work in Excel 2003 and Excel 2007.

Also, if "Cancel" is clicked, I do not want to show any of the above / ribbon, as user is supposed to get a protected view of the excel dashboard.

Comment: I have already tried the following ....................................................................

Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"....................

This does not work. It just displays for the time being, but after the application is closed, ribbon is not shown niether the bars.

Comment: I must be missing something but I don't understand your question. Why is the ribbon not visible in the first place? Is your code doing something to it?

Answer (score 1):

If the ribbon is closed by default, you can open it again by double clicking on one of the tabs (for instance, the Home tab).

(See [this](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excel2007tips/qt/excel2007_rib1.htm) for more details).

If, however, you wish to write an event to take place when the workbook opens, then use the `Workbook_Open()` event from the `ThisWorkbook` Excel Object.

Answer (score 0):

try this Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro " show.toolbar(""Ribbon"",true)"
to hide
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro " show.toolbar(""Ribbon"",false)"