# Excel Hide/Show all tabs on Ribbon except custom tab

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

How can I hide and show all the standard Excel ribbon tabs using VBA (not XML). I do not want to hide the whole ribbon (as is asked here: [VBA minimize ribbon in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019546/vba-minimize-ribbon-in-excel?rq=1)) just the tabs. I know how to use startFromScratch using XML so please do not suggest that or other XML solutions.

So far I have done an extensive Google search and looked at:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee390805(v=office.11).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.officeribbon.startfromscratch.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1
- [Customizing a ribbon with VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522048/customizing-a-ribbon-with-vba-in-excel)
- [Show Excel 2007 Ribbon in XLS file using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527645/show-excel-2007-ribbon-in-xls-file-using-excel-vba)
- [Show Excel 2007 Ribbon in XLS file using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527645/show-excel-2007-ribbon-in-xls-file-using-excel-vba)
- [Ribbon GUI Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867982/ribbon-gui-guidelines)
- [Excel CustomUI ribbon layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509769/excel-customui-ribbon-layout)
- http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win012.htm

What I am saying is I have already done an extensive search and tried many things without getting a result.

Comment: I really wish it was. Unfortunately I had already been to that page as part of my google search. Thanks for trying @PortlandRunner.

Comment: you have to use XML to customize the ribbon. You can make the defaults invisible, just need to know the name of the built in Tabs. e.g. hiding the **Home** tab: `<tabs> <tab idMso="TabHome" visible="false" /> </tabs>`

Comment: @PatricK, you're saying the xml of my custom ribbon-tab can hide the default ribbon-tabs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How can I hide and show all the standard Excel ribbon tabs using VBA (not XML)

The answer is "**YOU CAN'T**".

AFAIK, you can't do that using VBA. Unfortunately VBA doesn't expose the tabs. The only options that you have are as shown in the image below

[image]

So you can work with the commandbar, commandbarButton, commandbarComboBox etc...

You can say that `Set cbar = Application.CommandBars("Ribbon")` but after that, the problem that you will face is how to get a handle for the tabs.

**What you can do with the Ribbon using VBA:**

- Determine whether a particular control is Enabled/Visible/Pressed(Toggleboxes/CheckBoxes)
- Get a control's label, screen tip, or supertip Display the image associated with a
  control.
- Execute a particular control.

**What you can't do with the Ribbon using VBA:**

- Determine which tab is currently selected.
- Activate a particular tab.
- Hide a particular tab
- Add a new tab.
- Add a new group to a tab.
- Add a new control.
- Remove/Disable/Hide a control.

You can however use XML to achieve what you want. For example

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabReview" visible="false" />
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

But I guess you do not want to go via the XML Route.

Answer (score 10):

You can indeed hide/show ribbons using VBA.  Here is an example:

```html
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
  <tabs>
  <!-- EXCEL BUILT-IN TABS -->
    <tab idMso="TabDeveloper" getVisible="GetVisible">
   <group idMso="GroupCode" visible="true"/>
   <group idMso="GroupAddins" visible="true"/>
   <group idMso="GroupControls" visible="true"/>
   <group idMso="GroupXml" visible="true"/>
   <group idMso="GroupModify" visible="true"/>
 </tab>
  </tabs>
</ribbon>
```

1. Setup your XML file.
2. Setup your VBA script.

   `Sub GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef MakeVisible)
   Select Case control.ID
       Case "TabDeveloper":            MakeVisible = True
       Case "TabHome":                 MakeVisible = True
       Case "TabInsert":               MakeVisible = True
       Case "TabPageLayoutExcel":      MakeVisible = True
       Case "TabFormulas":             MakeVisible = True
       Case "TabData":                 MakeVisible = True
       Case "TabReview":               MakeVisible = True
       Case "TabView":                 MakeVisible = True
       Case "TabAddIns":               MakeVisible = True
       Case "TabBackgroundRemoval":    MakeVisible = True
   End Sub`
3. Download this file for a list of Control IDs for MS Office.
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6627

Tip:  Be sure to close your Excel Workbook that includes the ribbon you are editing before editing the XML ribbon file.  I have found that it sometimes erases my VBA code (I don't know why, it just does).

Answer (score 4):

To Activate a particular tab

> In Microsoft Office 2010, you activate a custom tab by using the
> ActivateTab method of the IRibbonUI object
>
> You use the ActivateTabMso
> method for built-in tabs and ActivateTabQ for tabs shared between
> multiple add-ins.
>
> ActivateTabQ also requires an additional
> String-type parameter that specifies the namespace of the add-in

In XML specify

```
customUI onLoad="RibbonOnLoad" xmlns=etc
```

In VBA

```
Public gRibbonUI As IRibbonUI 

Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)

   Set gRibbonUI = ribbon

End Sub
```

Then in code

```
gRibbonUI.ActivateTab "MyTabID"

gRibbonUI.ActivateTabMso "TabHome"
```

Answer (score 3):

First, open the Excel sheet which you want hide the ribbon tab on, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. Insert new code module and add following code:

```
Private Sub hide()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"",False)
End sub
```

Comment: I think you are mistaken on the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You can use on the XML like these:

> < ribbon startFromScratch="true" >

check this link:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win012.htm

Comment: thanks for your answer but I specifically said "I know how to use startFromScratch using XML so please do not suggest that". Please read questions carefully in future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this XML for Excel I have tested:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
<tabs>
    <tab idMso="TabHome" visible="false" />
    <tab idMso="TabInsert" visible="false" />
    <tab idMso="TabFormulas" visible="false" />
    <tab idMso="TabData" visible="false" />
    <tab idMso="TabReview" visible="false" />
    <tab idMso="TabView" visible="false" />
    <tab idMso="TabDeveloper" visible="false" />
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

[image: XML Code]

Result:
[image: ExcelApp]