# Disable Manage button on Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am updating this post because I didn't find something to solve this problem yet.

How can I disable button "Manage" in Power Pivot tab in excel 2010.
The problem is that I want the users to refresh a power pivot and have all the good stuff (analytics etc.) but I also want to hide my work in the database of the power pivot. So disabling the "Manage" button of the data base with something like password I believe could be a solution. Can I disable/enable "Manage" button with Vba code? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Bad news is power pivot is not accessible in excel 2010 through VBA. Though from excel 2013 onward, this is available to some extent. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn133245%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Maybe you can try Ribbon controlling workaround, but thats another story and would not serve your purpose as well. If you are interested, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967283/excel-hide-show-all-tabs-on-ribbon-except-custom-tab).

Comment: welcome. If you get further on this, please update this post for future reference.