# Excel ribbon toggle using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

I would like to toggle the Excel ribbon when Excel opens. For example, when Excel opens it always show the "Start" ribbon, but I want to set the another one "DeveloperTab" using VBA.

How to get the idMso for the excel ribbon?

Comment: Check out [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19970060/4717755) to see if it sheds any light on your situation

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with a class and a bit of XML. Here is the example file in [GitHub](https://github.com/StackOverflow-projects/52843704). If you copy the `.xlam` file to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\` directory, every time Excel opens the Developer tab will get focus. To create create/edit the XML ribbon in Excel use [Custom UI Editor Tool](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winfiles/OfficeCustomUIEditorSetup.zip).

#### Example video

[image: screenshot]

#### Ribbon class

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Ribbon_Load(ribbonUI As IRibbonUI)
On Error GoTo ErrTrap

    ribbonUI.ActivateTabMso ("TabDeveloper")

ExitProcedure:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub

ErrTrap:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case Else
            Debug.Print "Error #: " & Err.Number & " |Error Description: " & Err.Description
    End Select
    Resume ExitProcedure
    Resume 'for debugging

End Sub
```

#### XML Code

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
    <ribbon>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```