# Delete user ribbon from file

Tags: excel, vba

I have .xlsb file with user ribbon (i made it in "Custom UI Editor For Microsoft Office").
[image]

I want automatically delete (or hide) this ribbon from file (with VBA).
Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro of the manual removal process?

Comment: How to remove it manually? I can remove it, when edit XML structure of xlsb file with Custom UI Editor. I don't know how to remove it with excel-tools.

Comment: Does the ribbon show in the tabs menu if you right-click the ribbon click customize?

Comment: No. If i select "All tabs", there are no my ribbon too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel Hide/Show all tabs on Ribbon except custom tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967283/excel-hide-show-all-tabs-on-ribbon-except-custom-tab). Or to put it shortly: What you want to do is not possible with VBA.

Comment: Thank you, it's very sad. You can post it like an answer and i will mark it.

Comment: It is not true. You can Hide a custom tab using VBA

Comment: @Siddharth: Ah, ok, would be nice if you could post how to do it. Or maybe I got the question wrong.

Comment: It is slightly complex. Let me create an sample file and explain it with that. gimme an hours time. I am in the office...

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/officetalk2007/ee390805(v=office.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) resp. [this](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win012.htm). Thanks for correcting me. It is indeed possible to hide a custom tab as well. I only knew how to use getvisible for elements on the tab.

Comment: I managed to get some time so I created a sample. One moment, posting an answer

Comment: @Storax: Just visited those links.. yes you are right.

Comment: Your question 6 months ago was different. I answered it accordingly. For your new requirement, you need to ask a new quesiton. Please do nto edit the question to completely change the requirement after 6 months :)

Comment: I have rolled back the changes that you made. Please ask a new quesiton. Feel free to link this question in your new quesiton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this demonstration, you need **CustomUI Editor** and **Excel**(*Obviously*)

Create a new workbook and save it as say **AlexExample.xlsm**

**[A]** Open VBE, and insert a module. Paste this code in the module

```
Option Explicit

Dim Ribn As IRibbonUI
Public RibnTag As String

Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)   
    Set Ribn = ribbon
End Sub

Sub GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef visible)
    Select Case RibnTag
    Case "ShowTab": visible = True
    Case "HideTab": visible = False
    End Select
End Sub

Sub ShowMyRibbonTab()
    RibnTag = "ShowTab"
    If Not Ribn Is Nothing Then
        Ribn.Invalidate
    Else
        MsgBox "Couldn't get the ribbon object. Please close and restart the workbook"
    End If
End Sub

Sub HideMyRibbonTab()
    RibnTag = "HideTab"
    If Not Ribn Is Nothing Then
        Ribn.Invalidate
    Else
        MsgBox "Couldn't get the ribbon object. Please close and restart the workbook"
    End If
End Sub
```

**[B]** Open the ThisWorkbook code area and paste this code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    RibnTag = "ShowTab"
End Sub
```

**[C]** Go to the sheet and create 2 buttons (Form Control). `SHOW` and `HIDE` as shown below. Right click on the button and assign the macro `ShowMyRibbonTab` to **SHOW** and `HideMyRibbonTab` to **HIDE**

[image]

**[D]** Next Open CustomUI Editor and open the Excel File from there. Insert `customUI.xml` and paste the below code there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI onLoad="RibbonOnLoad" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="MyCustomTab" label="AlexsTab" getVisible="GetVisible" tag="AlexsTab" >
    </tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Save and close the file and you are done.

**SAMPLE FILE**: https://www.dropbox.com/s/izzbwpcmqtyoibd/AlexExample.xlsm?dl=0

[image]

Comment: Thank your for your comment, it works very good. But it does not resolve my problem. I have .xlsb file with my ribbon and macroses. Then i want to clear it from macroses and hide ribbon (i need to share this file w/o my information). Easiest way to clear it from macro is hide ribbon and save it in .xlsx format, but when i reopened this xlsx file i have alert with error (Cannot run the macro "RibbonOnLoad", because macroses is cleared). Any advices?

Comment: Your question 6 months ago was different. I answered it accordingly. For your new requirement, you need to ask a new quesiton. Please do nto edit the question to completely change the requirement after 6 months :)