# Is there a way to make Ribbon changes in excel unique to the current workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

This maybe a simple/ridiculous question, but I am trying to make changes to the ribbon in excel (removing all other tabs and just having my own with macros etc).
This is to be used as a basic data entry workbook for other users...

My only issue is that when the changes are made it applies it to every other workbook that I open in excel, I was thinking that there should just a setting that you could change to apply the changes. But looking online I am thinking that I need some VBA, that changes the ribbon on opening and closing of the spreadsheet?

Can anyone confirm/deny this? point me in the right direction?

Comment: No VBA required - see Ron's pages here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm

Comment: Also, SO responses, other links here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967283/excel-hide-show-all-tabs-on-ribbon-except-custom-tab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel Hide/Show all tabs on Ribbon except custom tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967283/excel-hide-show-all-tabs-on-ribbon-except-custom-tab)

Answer (score 1):

You can embed your ribbon customizations along with VBA macros into a macro-enabled workbook, so your customizations will be available only to the particular file. The [samples](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win012.htm) that shows how to hide or display ribbon tab/group with `getVisible` callbacks are available for download.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies but it seems as though the only way to do what I wanted to download an UI editor...
Unfortunately, I am limited to what I can download on a work PC/also I just presumed that with a bit of quick VBA magic I would be able to achive what I wanted. But it seems as though that VBA can't edit the ribbon without help from the UI editor.
I think I will just leave the ribbon alone for now!

Comment: You can unzip the open xml document and do the required customizations without any editor.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this:
https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor

This project contains a great guide that you need to read in order to address your question. I will not go over specifics, as you asked to be pointed into the right direction.

The README file specifies how you can add a custom tab/buttons etc. to a particular excel file. This tab will not show up in any other workbook, as it will be encoded directly in the workbook.

So to shortly answer your question - yes, it is possible. Please see the attached documentation, as I cannot guess what you intend to do, as you did not describe what specific effect you wish to achieve.

Comment: The tool is just an editor for the ribbon XML markup. You can use any editor for the Ribbon XML.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes it is an editor, but did you go through the documentation? It contains all the information you need with instructions on how to achieve your desired effect. Links provided in the REAMDE will guide you further. That or I did not quite understand the "point me in the right direction" part.