# Custom-UI: Force Developer-Tab to be visible

Tags: ms-word, custom-ui

I have a MS-Word template where the user sometimes will have to edit content controls.

Therefore I would like to **force the developer tab to be visible** whenever a document based on this template is opened.

I changed the CustomUI:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabDeveloper" visible="true" />
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

No error is thrown when the document is opened - but the Developer tab isn't visible.

Any thing else I have to consider, to force the tab to be visible?

(Vice versa works: hiding a visible Developer-Tab by setting visible to false)
(There is no VBA attached to the document.)

Answer (score 0):

OK - sometimes a short break helps:

I am adding a custom tab containing the relevant buttons from the developer tab. Plus: renaming them :-)

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="Abnahme" label="Abnahmedokument">
                <group id="x" label="Eingabefelder">
                   <button idMso="ContentControlText" label="neues Eingabefeld" size="large"/>
                   <button idMso="ControlProperties" label="Eingabefeld bearbeiten"  size="large"/>
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 0):

### I know of no method other than user education.

You could, in your distribution template, add your own duplicate tab or a tab that has the controls for Content Controls. Better practice is probably to put the Content Control tools on your own additional tab and ignore the Developer Tab.

See also [Hide/Show all tabs on Ribbon except Custom tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967283/excel-hide-show-all-tabs-on-ribbon-except-custom-tab) which also says there is no method available via VBA.

---

*The following caveat is for someone finding your question in a web search and thinking about using the **Word.OfficeUI** file and finding this question in a web search.* It does not appear that you are doing that.

### For customization distribution, the UI editor in Word is a very poor tool. It is intended for personal use.

**The Word.OfficeUI file produced by Word will overwrite any user customizations including QAT customizations.** Placing that on a user's computer is mean and dictatorial just like overwriting the Normal template. It is a bad practice.

For distribution, you should be editing the XML of a [global template](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global). Likewise, such a template is the best method of distributing other user interface customizations like macros and building blocks. The methods for doing this are explored in the book [RibbonX: Customizing the Ribbon User Interfac](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470191112)e and on Greg Maxey's page: [Customize the Office Ribbon: It doesn't take rocket science](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html).

Comment: Using my own tab came to my mind during lunch :-) see answer below. And yes: I am already using Office Ribbon X editor